# Prove $f: X \to Y$ is bijective if there are functions $g: Y \to X$ and $h: Y \to X$ such that $g(f(x)) = x$ and $f(h(y)) = y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. How can you prove that $f: X \to Y$ is bijective? Can you give me hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The condition says that $f$ has a left- und right-inverse.

Both inverses are equal, since for each $y\in Y$, $g(y) = g(f(h(y)) = h(y)$.

Then $f$ has an inverse written $f^{-1}=h=g$.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Hint: every element in $Y$ has a unique preimage.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The conditions can be written as $\DeclareMathOperator\id{id}$
$$g\circ f=\id_Y\quad\text{and}\quad h\circ f=\id X. $$
Now a basic result in elementary set theory is that

> If a composition is injective, the first function (in the composition order) is injective.
>
> If a composition is surjective, the second function is surjective.